# Python asyncio with multiple long running task producing no event loop error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio, event-loop

I am currently working on a script for some web scraping related activity and recently decided to move to asyncio on python 3.5.2 version.
There are 3 coroutines `producer`, `processor` and `consumer` each of them is infinitely running task.
Also inside `processor` and `producer` I have to make network request so I want to spawn those requests in separate thread and wait on them.
Though it would have been better if I could possibly also create Pool for making external requests at places `loop.run_in_executor` which I am not able to achieve currently.

The script for the producer consumer and processor is

```
import feedparser
import asyncio

def getEventLoop():
    loop = None
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    return loop

loop = getEventLoop()
link_queue = asyncio.Queue(100)
item_queue = asyncio.Queue(200)

async def addItem(item):
    #Saving into database
    pass
async def processor():
    # logger.info("Started processor")
    while True:
        news_job = await link_queue.get()
        link, source = news_job
        try:
            parsedData = await loop.run_in_executor(None, feedparser.parse, link)
            map(item_queue.put, parsedData.get("items"))
        except Exception as e:
            # logger.error("processor {} from {}".format(link, source), e)
            pass
        finally:
            link_queue.task_done()

async def consumer():
    # logger.info("Started consumer")
    while True:
        item = await item_queue.get()
        try:
            await addItem(item)
        except Exception as e:
            # logger.error("consumer {}".format(item.get("link")), e)
            pass
        finally:
            item_queue.task_done()


async def getItems(item_category):
    baseUrl = "https://www.example.com/"
    req = await loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, baseUrl+item_category)
    try:
        if req.status_code == 200:
            return [req.text.split(" ")] # Only dummy showcased
    except Exception as e:
        # logger.error("Exception in getItems for category {}".format(item_category), e)
        pass
    return []

async def produce_link(item_category):
    try:
        itemlist =[ item for item in  await getItems(item_category)]
        await asyncio.gather(map(link_queue.put, itemList))
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        # logger.error("Exception produce_link for {}".format(item_category), e)
        return False

async def producer():
    while True:
        item_category_list = ["a","b"] # Some dummy item categories
        def getAllItems():
            loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[ produce_link(item_category) for item_category in item_category_list]))
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, getAllItems)
        asyncio.sleep(random.randint(10,60))
    # logger.info("Stopped producer")

def run():
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(producer(), processor(), consumer()))
    loop.close()
```

I am getting following error **RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'**

```
  traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Projects\alphine\testscript.py", line 78, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(produce(), processor(), consumer()))
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "D:\Projects\alphine\testscript.py", line 73, in produce
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, getAllItems)
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\alphine\testscript.py", line 72, in getAllItems
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[ produce_link(item_category) for item_category in item_category_list]))
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 617, in gather
    fut = ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 546, in ensure_future
    loop = events.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 632, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 578, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
  RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

What is the root problem in my script which is causing this error?
Any other inputs are also welcomed.

Comment: Why do you need threads to make network requests? Asyncio is perfectly capable of running network code asynchronously - in fact, it's designed for that use case. Also, don't attempt to create more than one event loop in a single program, a single event loop is normally enough to service an application's async needs.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes acknowledged. But I am also using feedparser library which have its own implementation. So I would be needing to run it into other thread.

Comment: Oh, I see, that part is fine, `run_in_executor` is designed to cover that use case (along with CPU-bound code). The part that is the actual problem is the use of `loop.run_until_complete` in `producer`. You should simply `await asyncio.gather(...)` directly. Then the various hacks with multiple event loops should just disappear. And if you run into problems with that, you can ask a question, ideally accompanied by a runnable example that shows the problem.